# Bootstrap 4 wrapping and ordering issue

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I am wrapping text around an image which works but when i scale to mobile width the image should order-last and follow after the text, not before.

When i remove the  it is working but of course the text is not wrapping around the image anymore.

Here is a fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/cyzj1xrw/

The code:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-12">

            <div class="col order-last">
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="" style="" class="float-md-left float-none mr-3 mb-3 about-img">
            </div>

            <div class="col order-first">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo suscipit facilis ipsum ullam reiciendis odio error iste neque ratione libero rem accusamus voluptatibus, nihil unde maiores sunt nisi. Assumenda, consectetur.Illo suscipit facilis ipsum ullam
                reiciendis odio error iste neque ratione libero rem accusamus voluptatibus, nihil unde maiores sunt nisi. Assumenda, consectetur.Illo suscipit facilis ipsum ullam reiciendis odio error iste neque ratione limaiores sunt nisi. Assumenda,
                consectetur.Illo suscipit facilis ipsum ullam reiciendis odio error iste neque ratione libero rem accusamus voluptatibus, nihil unde maiores sunt nisi. Assumenda, consectetur.Illo suscipit facilis ipsum ullam reiciendis odio error isteneque ratione libero rem accusamus voluptatibus, nihil unde maiores sunt nisi. Assumenda, consectetur.bero rem accusamus voluptatibus, nihil unde maiores sunt nisi. Assumenda, consectetur.
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: what you exactly want?

Comment: you can use only on bootstrap column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wrap the column in the row. like this.
if you want to responsive then use responsive class [`order-sm-last` etc].

Working [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/cyzj1xrw/1/)

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-12">
           <div class="d-sm-flex d-md-block row">
            <div class="col col-sm-12 order-sm-last order-md-0">
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="" style="" class="float-md-left float-none mr-3 mb-3 about-img">
            </div>

            <div class="col col-sm-12 order-sm-first order-md-0">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo suscipit facilis ipsum ullam reiciendis odio error iste neque ratione libero rem accusamus voluptatibus, nihil unde maiores sunt nisi. Assumenda, consectetur.Illo suscipit facilis ipsum ullam
                reiciendis odio error iste neque ratione libero rem accusamus voluptatibus, nihil unde maiores sunt nisi. Assumenda, consectetur.Illo suscipit facilis ipsum ullam reiciendis odio error iste neque ratione limaiores sunt nisi. Assumenda,
                consectetur.Illo suscipit facilis ipsum ullam reiciendis odio error iste neque ratione libero rem accusamus voluptatibus, nihil unde maiores sunt nisi. Assumenda, consectetur.Illo suscipit facilis ipsum ullam reiciendis odio error isteneque ratione libero rem accusamus voluptatibus, nihil unde maiores sunt nisi. Assumenda, consectetur.bero rem accusamus voluptatibus, nihil unde maiores sunt nisi. Assumenda, consectetur.
            </div>
         </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The `order-*` classes in Bootstrap 4 use flexbox, but this is not working because the child `col` divs are not contained in a `row`. An easier option is to use the `col-12` with `d-flex` (`display:flex`)...

Since you only need the flex ordering to work on smaller (mobile) widths, use `d-sm-block` to allow the img to float left on larger (`sm-and-up`) widths. The `order-first` on the 2nd `div` will kick in on mobile.

https://www.codeply.com/go/DNJU8bTtgy

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 d-flex flex-row flex-wrap d-sm-block">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="" class="mr-3 mb-3 float-sm-left float-none about-img">
            <div class="order-first">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo suscipit facilis ipsum ullam reiciendis odio error iste neque ratione libero rem accusamus voluptatibus, nihil unde maiores sunt nisi. Assumenda, consectetur.Illo suscipit facilis ipsum ullam
                reiciendis odio error iste neque ratione libero rem accusamus voluptatibus, nihil unde maiores sunt nisi. Assumenda, consectetur.Illo suscipit facilis ipsum ullam reiciendis odio error iste neque ratione limaiores sunt nisi. Assumenda,
                consectetur.Illo suscipit tacilis ipsum ullam reiciendis odio error iste neque ratione libero rem accusamus voluptatibus, nihil unde maiores sunt nisi. Assumenda, consectetur.Illo suscipit facilis ipsum ullam reiciendis odio error iste
                neque ratione libero rem accusamus voluptatibus, nihil unde maiores sunt nisi. Assumenda, consectetur.bero rem accusamus voluptatibus, nihil unde maiores sunt nisi. Assumenda, consectetur.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it necessary to use `flex-row`? I think it works just fine without using it.

Answer (score 0):

You can make this by adding `custom class` with `col` like this

```css
@media screen and (max-width: 767px) {
  
    .flex-container {
      padding: 0;
      margin: 0;
      list-style: none;
      display: flex;
      -webkit-flex-flow: row wrap;
      flex-flow: row wrap;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-9gVQ4dYFwwWSjIDZnLEWnxCjeSWFphJiwGPXr1jddIhOegiu1FwO5qRGvFXOdJZ4" crossorigin="anonymous">

<div class="container">
    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-12">
 
            <div class="col flex-container">
              <div class="order-last">
                <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="" style="" class="float-md-left float-none mr-3 mb-3 about-img">
              </div>
              <div class="order-first">
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo suscipit facilis ipsum ullam reiciendis odio error iste neque ratione libero rem accusamus voluptatibus, nihil unde maiores sunt nisi. Assumenda, consectetur.Illo suscipit facilis ipsum ullam
                reiciendis odio error iste neque ratione libero rem accusamus voluptatibus, nihil unde maiores sunt nisi. Assumenda, consectetur.Illo suscipit facilis ipsum ullam reiciendis odio error iste neque ratione limaiores sunt nisi. Assumenda,
                consectetur.Illo suscipit facilis ipsum ullam reiciendis odio error iste neque ratione libero rem accusamus voluptatibus, nihil unde maiores sunt nisi. Assumenda, consectetur.Illo suscipit facilis ipsum ullam reiciendis odio error iste
                neque ratione libero rem accusamus voluptatibus, nihil unde maiores sunt nisi. Assumenda, consectetur.bero rem accusamus voluptatibus, nihil unde maiores sunt nisi. Assumenda, consectetur.
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Your updated fiddle [here](https://jsfiddle.net/cyzj1xrw/2/)

Answer (score 0):

This code behaves similar to that of @ZimStem. Only use  `d-flex flex-wrap d-sm-block` to the `col-12` div and `mr-3 mb-3 float-sm-left float-none order-last about-img` classes to the `img` and use a `p` tag for the paragraph.

```html
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/twitter-bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-12 d-flex flex-wrap d-sm-block">
            <img src="http://via.placeholder.com/350x150" alt="" class="mr-3 mb-3 float-sm-left float-none order-last about-img">
            <p>
                Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo suscipit facilis ipsum ullam reiciendis odio error iste neque ratione libero rem accusamus voluptatibus, nihil unde maiores sunt nisi. Assumenda, consectetur.Illo suscipit facilis ipsum ullam
                reiciendis odio error iste neque ratione libero rem accusamus voluptatibus, nihil unde maiores sunt nisi. Assumenda, consectetur.Illo suscipit facilis ipsum ullam reiciendis odio error iste neque ratione limaiores sunt nisi. Assumenda,
                consectetur.Illo suscipit tacilis ipsum ullam reiciendis odio error iste neque ratione libero rem accusamus voluptatibus, nihil unde maiores sunt nisi. Assumenda, consectetur.Illo suscipit facilis ipsum ullam reiciendis odio error iste
                neque ratione libero rem accusamus voluptatibus, nihil unde maiores sunt nisi. Assumenda, consectetur.bero rem accusamus voluptatibus, nihil unde maiores sunt nisi. Assumenda, consectetur.
            </p>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Check this link on [CodePen](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/MGrJzY)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot. The image should be responsive, so i came to this solution.

Fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/5tngyLb0/1/

Code:

```
<div class="container my-5">

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-12">

            <div class="d-sm-flex d-md-block row">
                <div class="col col-12 col-md-6 order-sm-last order-md-0">
                    <img src="https://www.w3schools.com/howto/img_fjords.jpg" class="img-fluid float-md-left float-none mr-3 mb-3">
                </div>

                <div class="col order-first order-md-0">

                    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Illo suscipit facilis ipsum ullam reiciendis odio error iste neque ratione libero rem accusamus voluptatibus, nihil unde maiores sunt nisi. Assumenda, consectetur.Illo suscipit facilis ipsum ullam
                    reiciendis odio error iste neque ratione libero rem accusamus voluptatibus, nihil unde maiores sunt nisi. Assumenda, consectetur.Illo suscipit facilis ipsum ullam reiciendis odio error iste neque ratione limaiores sunt nisi. Assumenda,
                    consectetur.Illo suscipit tacilis ipsum ullam reiciendis odio error iste neque ratione libero rem accusamus voluptatibus, nihil unde maiores sunt nisi. Assumenda, consectetur.Illo suscipit facilis ipsum ullam reiciendis odio error
                    iste neque ratione libero rem accusamus voluptatibus, nihil unde maiores sunt nisi. Assumenda, consectetur.bero rem accusamus voluptatibus, nihil unde maiores sunt nisi. Assumenda, consectetur.
                </div>

            </div>

        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```